# How to reorder Disk drivers in Navigation panel explorer Win10?

Tags: windows

I wonder if there was a way to change the disks' order in the left panel of windows explorer. As you see in the picture, mine goes F, G, H, E then D. It's anoying somtimes.

Anyone who was in this situation, please help me if you had solutions.

[image]

Comment: Don't they go in order of 'greatest free space' ?

Comment: Thankyou for replying. 
Im not sure what is the rules of order.
My F: has 300GB freespace
My G: 100gb
My H: 3gb
My E: 160gb....

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your Disk Management window...maybe this is the order your drive is actually partitioned and the lettering might be wrong and BTW which of your drive has the OS, none of the above drive icons has the little windows logo ?

Comment: Your navigation pane is also not displaying the This PC icon...also windows 10 no longer displays Libraries button in the navigation pane??

Comment: My This PC icon is at the bottom of the panel which is not shown in this picture.
Here is my Disk Manage screen
https://scontent.fhan5-7.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/71498053_3313902111968142_3415978625143406592_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_oc=AQn_Kk3HEKt6SvdaM0xxS81O-RPEfN9fUD6zc1h-Uydm1bSHnB-IWT13LjdfWtogkfaXxI-t2gHkW2x86bZzTLnR&_nc_ht=scontent.fhan5-7.fna&oh=e9dfecce3833577376337f30774261ec&oe=5DFA5EE4

Comment: next time you reply to a comment be sure to write first - @"then here the name of the person to whom you are replying without the quotes for example @TitKu 

this way the other person gets notified about the reply/comment

Comment: @TitKu well you are using multiple disks, so I am not sure if this is a lettering problem but in file explorer disable libraries and then check how they are displayed under "This PC".....btw also try changing the letters of the drive yourself in disk management.

Answer (score 0):

File Explorer sorts volume labels alphabetically. Remove the drive label or give the volumes a different label.